# Matplotlib - Weird Datetime format in axis after conversion

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to convert my axis labels from modified julian date (days since 1858-11-17) to a datetime. I got the conversion from float to datetime working, but when I try to format the axis labels just to display `"%Y-%m-%d"` I still get `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` in the axis label.

Here is my conversion code:

```
import datetime
MJD0 = datetime.datetime(year=1858, month=11, day=17)

def ConvertMJDDateTime(MJD):
    return MJD0 + datetime.timedelta(days=int(MJD))
```

And my plot formatting code:

```
labels = ax1.get_xticks()
datetimes = [ConvertMJDDateTime(t) for t in labels]
ax1.set_xticklabels(datetimes)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
yearsFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax1.format_xdata = yearsFmt
```

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: that is not what `format_xdata` does (it controls how the mouse-over data is displayed).  Look into `set_major_formatter()`

Comment: also, you should almost _never_ use `set_xtickslabels` it is dangerous and de-couples your ticks labels from your data.

Comment: @tcaswell what would you recommend instead of `set_xticklabels`? Tried using `set_major_formatter()` but the year format gets screwed up